# Matrix problem invovling orthogonal matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

> If $$P=\begin{bmatrix} 
> \cos\theta & \sin\theta \\
> -\sin\theta & \cos\theta
> \end{bmatrix}\text{ and } A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
>   And $Q=PAP'$ then $P'Q^{2009}P=?$

I noticed that $P$ is an orthogonal matrix so
$$P'=P^{-1}$$ and $P^2(\theta)=P(2\theta)$

$$Q^{2009}=P^{2009}A^{2009}(P^{-1})^{2009}$$
I am stuck at this step. Is there any property of orthogonal matrix that I can use here?

Comment: Think again: $Q^{2009}=P A^{2009} P^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Since $P' = P^{-1}$, we have $P P' = I$ and hence
$$P' Q^k P = P'QPP'QP\cdots P'QPP'QP = \underbrace{(P' Q P) \cdots (P' Q P)}_k = (P' Q P)^k .$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$A^\color{red}2 = \begin{pmatrix}1 & \color{red}2\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$A^\color{red}3 = \begin{pmatrix}1 & \color{red}3\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$A^\color{red}4 = \begin{pmatrix}1 & \color{red}4\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$$
 $$\dots$$

And  $$Q^{2009} = PA^{2009}P^{-1}$$